# calculate multiple values type to string

Tags: c#

i have two textboxes 1 called 'mtb_NETPAIE02' and 2 called 'mtb_TAXE02'
the format in the two textboxes is currency/money (double) i want to fix the error on this Code :

```
if (double.Parse(mtb_NETPAIE02.Text) >= 100001 )
{
    mtb_TAXE02.Text = (double.Parse(mtb_NETPAIE02.Text) / 5000 * double.Parse("12") 
                       + double.Parse("18").ToString("N2")).ToString();               
}
```

12 (12,00) and 18 (18,00) are money but 5000 is int .

how to make this right ?

Comment: "i want to fix the error on this Code" are you going to make us guess?  What error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not be using `double` if you're working with money; [you should be using `decimal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165788/2704659).

Secondly, you should use the literals for decimal, i.e. with the `M` suffix.

Finally, you are attempting to add the result of `decimal.Parse("18")` to the other numeric values, but you are converting it to a string first via `ToString("N2")`.  You should move the latter *outside* your parens to convert the whole result from the calculation into a string:

```
if (decimal.Parse(mtb_NETPAIE02.Text) >= 100001M )
{
    // notice the `M` in 5000M
    mtb_TAXE02.Text = (decimal.Parse(mtb_NETPAIE02.Text) / 
        5000M * decimal.Parse("12") + decimal.Parse("18")).ToString("N2");
}
```

Comment: thank you so much brother for your great help .... can you explain what 'M'  mean  plz ?

Comment: "M" means its a decimal literal.